# cannot redeclare function after upgrading to php 5.3

Tags: php, php-5.3, ioncube

I've tried to upgrade from php 5.2 to php 5.3 on my testing machine, and there's a commercial package used, which is encoded, and I cannot change it at all. It should be working with PHP 5.3, except it has a lcfirst function declared, so I get an error PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare lcfirst(). Is there any way that I could somehow workaround this, so that I could run it on PHP 5.3? Or is the only option to compile PHP without this function.

Comment: Start with the support address for the commercial package. Surely they must have dealt with this -- PHP 5.3 has been out for years.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not, you can't undeclare a function... they're going to have to change the name of their function.

As @Michael said, PHP 5.3 has been out for ages, seems a bit odd that they have hit this issue.

Comment: It is a longer supported product

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? You've got two choices, change your PHP version, or change the code. The latter point would be for the developers to do, granted.